# Cast between llvm struct

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In my development, a function returns a struct of type `{i8*, i64}`, and on the
call site I need to assign the return value to a struct of type `{some_struct*, i64}`.
One way to do it is to call the `mutateType()` method of `llvm::Value` on
the return value of the function call; however, I’m concerned that this `mutateType()`
method might be too disruptive (it’s discouraged to use it by the documentation).
Since LLVM does not support direct cast between structs. Is there any way I can safely
“cast” a value of one struct type to another?

Comment: You could use [extractvalue and inservalue](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractvalue-instruction), I think. I never have used inservalue myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution if you don't want to deal with individual struct members would be to do an alloca, store the struct to the alloca, bitcast the alloca, and then load the cast pointer. Note this might interact poorly if you are making use of type based alias analysis in llvm, such as with llvm generated from c or c++ code, but if you're dealing with pure llvm or disable strict aliasing, it shouldn't be a problem.